# Javascript form elements added to an array and then totaling the elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I need to create a form that accepts user input (integers), adds that input to an array, and then sums the integers and displays their total on the Web page as text. I feel like I am close to the solution but, when I press the submit button, nothing happens. I am very new to Javascript and this is a class assignment. Can anyone tell if this code looks right or suggest where there may be an error?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Adding Numbers</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<p><script type="javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
function addNums() {
var total = 0;
var intergers = new Array(5);
intergers[0] = document.forms[0].element[0].value;
intergers[1] = document.forms[0].element[1].value;
intergers[2] = document.forms[0].element[2].value;
intergers[3] = document.forms[0].element[3].value;
intergers[4] = document.forms[0].element[4].value;
for (i=0; i<intergers.length; i++) {
    total += intergers[i];
    }
return total;
document.write("The total for the intergers entered is " + total + "."</p>);
}   

/* ]]> */
</script><strong>Please enter an interger into each of the following text boxes.<br />
Press the Submit button to see a total of all the intergers.</strong></p>
<form action="" name="intergers" onsubmit="addNums();" >    
<p>1st Interger<br/>
    <input type="text" name="num1" value="" size="10" /></p>
<p>2nd Interger<br/>
    <input type="text" name="num2" value="" size="10" /></p>
<p>3rd Interger<br/>
    <input type="text" name="num3" value="" size="10" /></p>
<p>4th Interger<br/>
    <input type="text" name="num4" value="" size="10" /></p>
<p>5th Interger<br/>
    <input type="text" name="num5" value="" size="10" /></p>
<p><input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p> 
</form>
</body>
</html>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1):

**First of all, you have an extra R on all your *integers*! :-)**

One problem with your code is that input values are always strings, and JavaScript uses `+` for both number addition and string concatenation. You have to force all your values into numbers before adding them:

```
for (i=0; i<intergers.length; i++) {
    total += parseInt(intergers[i], 10);
}
```

or

```
for (i=0; i<intergers.length; i++) {
    total += +intergers[i], 10;
}
```

---

Edit: there are several other problems, I just realized... Some of them:

- Don't use `type="javascript"` in your script tags, just remove that.
- There is no `element` property on `document.forms[0]`. That should be `elements`.
- Your button will also be listed as one of those elements...
- You have to prevent your form from subitting, or you'll never see the result
- You're trying to use `document.write` in a context where it's double-wrong: the page is already loaded (so it would erase the whole page before outputting), and you're trying to call it after a `return` statement (where no code is reachable).
- You also have a `</p>` inside the call to document.write, and that's causing a syntax error.
- Tip: open your browser's developer tools, and always check the console for errors.

Comment: You are so very wrong on your first point http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/diffs.html . Just because the browser 'corrects' i.e. converts to html you should either write html in the first place or do xhmtl correctly.

Comment: Okay, I realize the part about CDATA was incorrect, I removed that. In any case, I assume the OP is only using the XHTML doctype because he copied/pasted the structure from somewhere else. Using HTML5 (or even HTML4 strict) would be recommended.